# Trigger on CaseComment Object has no coverage

Tags: unit-testing, triggers, salesforce, code-coverage, apex

I have a Trigger on CaseComment Object in my Org which has only one line of Code in It to call a static method from another apex class. But the trigger has 0% coverage. I have written a test Class to get the coverage, but it isn't working at all. Can anyone please let me know why it is not covering the trigger and how to cover it? Thanks in advance.

The trigger Code is

```
trigger CaseCommentTrigger on CaseComment (after Insert) {
    CaseCommentTriggerUtil.notifyCaseRequestorAndCreator(Trigger.New);
}
```

My test class is

```
@isTest
public with sharing class CaseCommentTriggerTest {
    @isTest
    public static void createCaseComment() {
        Case tCase = new Case();

        tCase.Status = 'New';
        tCase.Description = 'Test Description';
        tCase.Origin = 'Email';
        tCase.Priority = 'Low';
      
        INSERT tCase;
        
        CaseComment tComment = new CaseComment();
        tComment.ParentId = tCase.Id;
        tComment.CommentBody = 'Some Comment';
        tComment.IsPublished = TRUE;
        
        INSERT tComment;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without more info or ideally debug log. Does the test compile and pass ok? (no required fields missing etc). Are you sure it's deployed to the right org? Is the trigger active? What kind of notification does this do, an email? Is the org's Setup -> Deliverability set to "All email"?

Answer (score 0):

`CaseComment` is an object associated to a `Case`, so all you have to do is to change your trigger class to be used in Case object instead `CaseComment` object.

Your trigger should be like this:

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert) {

   CaseCommentTriggerUtil.notifyCaseRequestorAndCreator(Trigger.New);
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@isTest
public with sharing class CaseCommentTriggerTest {
    @isTest
    public static void createCaseComment() {
        Case tCase = new Case();

        tCase.Status = 'New';
        tCase.Description = 'Test Description';
        tCase.Origin = 'Email';
        tCase.Priority = 'Low';
      
        INSERT tCase;
        
        Test.StartTest();
        CaseComment tComment = new CaseComment();
        tComment.ParentId = tCase.Id;
        tComment.CommentBody = 'Some Comment';
        tComment.IsPublished = TRUE;
        
        INSERT tComment;
        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```